# The program is ignoring the very first row of data in first section of every sheet of input file, writing the data into final file starting from row 2

Tags: python, pandas, excel

```
import pandas as pd

def process_sheet(sheet_name, sheet_data):
    result_rows = []

    for prefix in sorted(set(row[1] // 10000 for row in sheet_data.itertuples(index=False)), key=str):
        rows_with_prefix = sheet_data[sheet_data.iloc[:, 1] // 10000 == int(prefix)]

        if not rows_with_prefix.empty:
            result_row = [None] * len(sheet_data.columns)
            result_row[1] = int(prefix)  # Set the 3-digit value in the 2nd column
            result_rows.extend([result_row] + rows_with_prefix.values.tolist())

    return pd.DataFrame(result_rows)

def process_excel(input_filename, output_filename):
    input_excel = pd.ExcelFile(input_filename)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_filename, engine='xlsxwriter')

    for sheet_name in input_excel.sheet_names:
        sheet_data = input_excel.parse(sheet_name)
        processed_data = process_sheet(sheet_name, sheet_data)

        # Write data to the new Excel file without the header row
        processed_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, index=False, header=False)

    writer._save()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_file = "output_data.xlsx"
    output_file = "final.xlsx"
    process_excel(input_file, output_file)
```

This code ignores the very first row of dataset from the input file and continues to append the data in output file from the second row.

Comment: there is a lot of "code" in this for iterable `for prefix in sorted(set(row[1] // 10000 for row in sheet_data.itertuples(index=False)), key=str):`